# Python: type annotate class decorator return type

Tags: python, decorator, typing

How to annotate a class decorator that extends a class with additional members?

I have the following example where my class decorator inserts an async `new` function that calls the provided class' `ainit`. This code runs correctly, but the type returned by `optimizer` is the original type, and `new` is missing. How can I improve annotation, if possible?

```
AinitArguments = ParamSpec("AinitArguments")

class Optimizerable(Protocol):
    ainit: Callable[AinitArguments, None]


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Optimizerable)


def optimizer(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
    @classmethod
    async def new(cls: Type[T], *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        self = cls.__new__(cls)
        await self.ainit(*args, **kwargs)
        return self

    setattr(cls, "new", new)
    return cls

@optimizer
class Myclass:
    async def ainit(self, a: int, b: float) -> None:
        pass # stub
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you can't really do this yet https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Python doesn't have a native type for an `Intersection` to represent a concrete class implementing two bases (either explicitly through inheritance or duck-typing like with protocol).

What you want would look like this (which just isnt possible yet):

```
class Optimizerable(Protocol):
    ainit: Callable[AinitArguments, None]

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Optimizerable)

class Optimized(Protocol[T]):
    async def new(cls: Type[T], *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        ...

def optimizer(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[Intersection[T, Optimized[T]]]:
    ...
```

I would either refactor this code to use a Mixin to add the method, or simply keep `new` as a stateless function, which avoids complex class structures entirely:

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Optimizerable)


async def optimized_new(cls: Type[T], *args, **kwargs) -> T:
    self = cls.__new__(cls)
    await self.ainit(*args, **kwargs)
    return self
```

Comment: That is unfortunate. Indeed I stumbled on the same thread and problem. The issue looks rather stale, I hope the discussion continues. For now I will leave the question unanswered in the hope a solution appears some time soon.

Comment: @AartStuurman Yeah, unfortunately its been open for a very long time. Python always feels very limiting after working on typescript code. For reference I'm familiar with the issue after playing with the dataclasses json library which also suffers from this issue. In this case they seem to have gone for the mixin route: https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json#approach-2-inherit-from-a-mixin

Comment: Yeah, I come from C++ and I'm struggling. The unfortunate thing with a mixin is that the arguments will be args kwargs, where theoretically if this feature existed a decorator could be created that creates a new that takes the same arguments as ainit.